# Can't run React Native official example

Tags: react-native, flowtype, create-react-native-app

Here's the code I copied from [React's Native website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input.html) that should render a text input with some formatting features:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here to translate!"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        />
        <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
          {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => PizzaTranslator);
```

I'm using [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app).

If I run

```
npm run flow
```

It displays lots of errors:

My question is - am I doing something wrong here, or the code from React's website is already outdated?

```
App.js:7
  7:   constructor(props) {
                   ^^^^^ parameter `props`. Missing annotation

App.js:9
  9:     this.state = {text: ''};
                      ^^^^^^^^^^ object literal. This type is incompatible with
  6: export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?

App.js:18
 18:           onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `setState`
 18:           onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                                                     ^^^^^^ property `text` of object literal. Property cannot be assigned on possibly undefined value
  6: export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?

App.js:21
 21:           {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
                           ^^^^ property `text`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value
 21:           {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
                ^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?


Found 4 errors


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here to translate!"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        />
        <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
          {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => PizzaTranslator);
```

Comment: You may need to make changes as per flow syntax, btw what is your project root directory name

Comment: @JigarShah The directory name is pizza.

Comment: Why do you run Flow if there are no Flow types to check? And why run a type checker on copied example code anyway? Just skip type checking the example. That is not in the instructions either. If you want to learn the very basics you should stick to the steps they actually ask you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `super(props)` is incorrect in this context. So I changed the

```
export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component
```

to

```
class PizzaTranslator extends Component
```

then called it from `export default class Main` and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the react-native documentation was written without flow annotations for the purpose of making it easier to read for people not versed in flow.